# Compute By Clause Error In SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I am having a problem with this compute by clause

The statement is a simple select

```
Select 
    col1, sum(col2) 
from 
    table1 t1
join
    table2 t2 on t1.col1=t2.col1
where 
    year(t1.coldate) = 2012
Group by 
    col1
order by 
    col1
Compute 
    Sum(col2), avg(col2) by col1
```

The error message I keep getting is

> Msg 411, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   COMPUTE clause #1, aggregate expression #1 is not in the select list..

here is my full code [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a55a/2)

what i want was to show TransactionID and TotalMedicine (derived from the quantity number of sold Medicine) where the year when the medicine was sold in 2012. Also count the number and the average sold drugs.

Comment: This clause is deprecated in sql2008 and is removed in 2012. [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181708(v=sql.105).aspx). You could use grouping sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `COMPUTE` can be applied to the columns in the `SELECT` clause, so you have to define aliases and use them:

```
Select 
    col1, sum(col2) AS sum_col2                  --- alias
...

Compute 
    Sum(sum_col2), avg(sum_col2) by col1 ;       --- using the alias
```

And I'm not sure that you want the `by col1` since you are already grouping by that column. If you want the total sum and average of the `sum_col2`, remove the `by col1` from the `COMPUTE`.

Another (irrelevant to your problem) issue is the `where year(t1.coldate) = 2012` condition which is not **[sargable](http://msmvps.com/blogs/robfarley/archive/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server.aspx)**. I'd use this `where coldate >= '20120101' and coldate < '20130101'` so an index on `coldate` would be used. The query after all the changes

... and after your comments and some experiments (which make think it's not trivial to combine `GROUP BY` with `COMPUTE`), perhaps you should remove the `GROUP BY`:

```
Select 
    t1.col1, col2
from 
    table1 t1
join
    table2 t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1
where 
    coldate >= '20120101' and coldate < '20130101'
order by 
    col1
Compute 
    Sum(col2), Avg(col2)  by col1                 -- for every col1
Compute 
    Sum(col2), Avg(col2)                          -- and overall
  ;
```

---

As @Bogdan Shalean correctly commented, `COMPUTE` is under deprecation and you should use `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS`:

```
Select 
    t1.col1, 
    SUM(col2) AS TotalMedicine,
    AVG(col2) AS AverageMedicine
from 
    table1 t1
join
    table2 t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1
where 
    coldate >= '20120101' and coldate < '20130101'
Group By Grouping Sets
    ( (col1),
      ()
    )
  ;
```

See **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a55a/32)** test.

Comment: what i want to compute is the total sum and average of the col2 not the sum(col2) and i kept getting that error..

Comment: i'm sorry to say this but i still get the same error...
here is my full code http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a55a

what i want was to show TransactionID and TotalMedicine (derived from the quantity number of sold Medicine) where the year when the medicine was sold in 2012. Also count the number and the average sold drugs.
i wanna use below syntax
(sum, year, group by, compute, avg)

Comment: I don't see the query there, only the data. Perhaps you linked the wrong fiddle.

Comment: Have you tried to run this in your local SQL-Server or only in SQL-Fiddle? I think there is some issue with `compute` and some connection methods.

Comment: i have tried both,local sql server and the sql fiddle..
it got the same error

Comment: This (without `GROUP BY`) [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a55a/26) works in my local SQL-Server 2008-R2

Comment: `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((col1), ())` = `GROUP BY ROLLUP(col1)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to [make your clauses match](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/70267), so try:

```
Select 
    col2, sum(col2)  
from 
    table1 t1 
join 
    table2 t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1 
where 
    year(t1.coldate) = 2012 
Group by 
    col1 
order by
    col1 
Compute 
    Sum(col2), avg(col2) by col1
```

Or something similar, I'd give you an exact answer, but would need more detail.

Comment: This will not reach the `COMPUTE` part. There will be error because you can't `SELECT col2` when you `GROUP BY col1`